# Examples of squeeze theorem with non-trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus

Is there examples of the squeeze theorem that don't involve trigonometric functions? Is there a general form of non-trigonometric functions where the squeeze theorem can be applied?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are different "squeeze theorems" and "squeeze techniques" and they apply to all sorts of functions. Would you  state specifically which theorem you are referring to?

Comment: The one that says: If $lim_{x \mapsto a} h(x) = lim_{x \mapsto a} g(x) = L$ and $h(x) \leq f(x) \leq g(x) \forall x$ then $lim_{x \mapsto a} f(x) = L$. This theorem is mainly used to find the limits for variations of $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$. I've been looking for examples of the squeeze theorem for other functions(linear, polynomial, exponential) but didn't found any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices that there exists $b>0$ such that $\forall x\in (a-b,a+b)\;(h(x)\leq f(x)\leq g(x)\;).$

A very common use  is to have $h(x)=K$ for all $x$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=K,$ to conclude that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=K.$

Sometimes we exclude the point $a$ from the domain of $f,g,$ and $h$ and sometimes we consider only  $x>a$ (or only  $x<a$). For example, for $0<x<1$ let $$f(x)= \frac {1}{\sqrt x} \left(\sqrt {\frac {1}{x}+1}\;-\sqrt {\frac {1}{x}-1}\;\right).$$  $$\text {We have  }\quad f(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt x}\cdot \frac {2}{\sqrt {\frac {1}{x}+1}\;+\sqrt {\frac {1}{x}-1}}.$$  $$ \text {So }\quad f(x)\leq \frac {1}{\sqrt x}\cdot \frac {2}{2\sqrt {\frac {1}{x}-1}}=\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-x}}=g(x)$$  $$\text {and }\quad h(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt {1+x}}=\frac {1}{\sqrt x}\cdot \frac {2}{2\sqrt {\frac {1}{x}+1}}\leq f(x).$$ Since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}h(x)=1=\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x),$ we obtain  $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=1.$

Comment: Not a very deep example as the squeeze method  is not the only way. I may be back with more.